# Problems to match classes based on route in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables

I've got a problem with assigning a class to the variable and then to the div based on his routing. I don't know what am I doing wrong, everything seems to be ok so where is the mistake then?  I'm super curious about what did I do wrong.

```js
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import About from './About'
import Home from './Home'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    home: {
        background: 'white',
    },
    about: {
        background: 'black',
    }
});

const App = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    let location = useLocation();
    let style;

    useEffect(() => {
        style = classes.home
        handleLocation()
        console.log('.')

    }, [location])

    const handleLocation = () => {
        if (location.pathname === "/") {
            style = classes.home
        } else if (location.pathname === '/about') {
            style = classes.about
        }
    }
    return (
    <div className={style}>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact>
                    <Home />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/about">
                    <About />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </div>
)
}

export default App
```

If something is unclear feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code :

```
 import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import About from './About'
import Home from './Home'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    home: {
        background: 'white',
    },
    about: {
        background: 'black',
    }
});

const App = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    let location = useLocation();

   

    const handleLocation = () => {
        if (location.pathname === "/") {
            return classes.home
        } else if (location.pathname === '/about') {
            return classes.about
        }else if(more if you want){
        return more class ....
       }
    }
    return (
    <div className={handleLocation()}>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact>
                    <Home />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/about">
                    <About />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </div>
)
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

React's components re-renders when a state or a prop change, so the style variable is neither a state nor a prop, Now when you update it, UI doesn't change because the component doesn't re-render

```js
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import About from './About'
import Home from './Home'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    home: {
        background: 'white',
    },
    about: {
        background: 'black',
    }
});

const App = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    let location = useLocation();

    return (
    <div className={ location.pathname === "/"  ? classes.home : location.pathname === "/about" ? classes.about : "" }>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact>
                    <Home />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/about">
                    <About />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </div>
)
}

export default App
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

.

You would need to either make style a state or secondly you can just do this directly

Comment: Thank you, but how about if there are more than 2 classes and routes that I want to use?

Comment: you can keep the name of the styles the same as the name of the route, and do this

`className={location.pathname.substr(1)}`